# How to include a web component library in an R Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, web-component

My ultimate goal is to take a GIF animation and provide basic controls like play/pause, scrubbing, speed up and slow down for it within my Shiny app.

I have found a web component library called [x-gif](https://github.com/geelen/x-gif) that seems to do what I want. However, I am having a hard time understanding how to include it in my Shiny project. From what I can understand, the original instructions are out of date as `<link rel="import">` appears to be completely deprecated. With my limited understanding of web development as a whole, I don't understand the non-deprecated alternatives.

Comment: You can use the shiny function `includeHTML()` to inject the HTML file into the page rather than `<link rel="import">`. You just need to get that content into the page source.

Comment: This worked, but looking at more errors it appears this package was made for a version of the web that doesn't exist anymore :(

Comment: Looks like x-gif is a 7 year old Web Component using HTML-Import which was part of _**Googles**_ V0 code, but did not become part of the V1 Web Component **standard**. Report it as an issue: https://github.com/geelen/x-gif/issues